# Las dimenciones del cuadro de leyenda son muy grades en plot

Tags: r, lista, imagen, objeto, plot

Hace como un año hice unos grafico en plot me quedaron como quería, ahora que estoy actualizando información de dichos gráficos tengo un problema con la leyenda, en los gráficos antriores el cuadro de la leyenda se ajustaba al texto pero ahora aun siendo el mismo texto/contenido el cuadro de la leyenda no se ajusta al texto y esta desproporción evita que se visualice la información, ya trate de modificarlo para que se vea mejor pero el problema persiste en el eje x.

No se como ajustar el cuadro en el eje x para que no tape tanto la inforación.

Este es mi código hace un año:

```
R<- read.csv("ONI.csv")
names(R)=c("#","AÑO","ENSO","PARAISO","COMALCALCO","VICENTE")
R$AÑO <- as.numeric(R$AÑO)
plot(R$AÑO,R$PARAISO,
     col="red",
     type = "l",
     ylab = "Precipitación total en mm",
     xlab = "Años",
     axes=FALSE ,
     main="Precipitación total y ONI | Periodo 1965-2016")
axis(2)
axis(1, at=c(1965,1975,1985,1995,2005,2015,2016))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(R$AÑO,R$COMALCALCO,
     col="blue",
     type = "l",
     ylab = "Precipitación total en mm",
     xlab = "Años",
     axes=FALSE ,
     main="")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(R$AÑO,R$VICENTE,
     col="green",
     type = "l",
     ylab = "Precipitación total en mm",
     xlab = "Años",
     axes=FALSE ,
     main="")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(R$AÑO,R$ENSO,
     col="black",
     type="l",
     lty=2,
     xaxt="n",
     yaxt="n",xlab="",
     ylab="",
     axes=FALSE ,
     main="")
axis(4,line = -1, at=c(-1.2,-0.6,-0.3,0,0.3,0.9,1.5)) 
segments(1965, 0, 2016, 0, lwd=1, col="orange")
mtext("ONI",side=4,line=1)
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("27034-PARAISO","27009-COMALCALCO","27053-VICENTE G.","ONI"),
       col=c('red', 'blue', "green","black"), lwd=1,lty = c(1,1,1,2),)
```

Y este el grafico que obtuve
[image: Grafico obtenido hace un año]

Pero ahora corro ese mismo codigo y obtengo esto

[image: como e puede ver la proporción del cuadro de leyenda no se ajusta y no se por que sucede esto]

Lo único que mas o menos funciono para intentar corregir esto fue agregar y.intersp = # a legend lo que corregir el eje y del cuadro de leyenda pero agrgar X.intersp = # no funciono para corregir el problema en el eje x.

```
legend("bottomleft", legend=c("27034-PARAISO","27009-COMALCALCO","27053-VICENTE G.","ONI"),
       col=c('red', 'blue', "green","black"), lwd=1,lty = c(1,1,1,2),y.intersp = 0.3)
```

Tras esto es lo mejor que pude corregir el problema
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan aconsejar ya que probé varias cosas y aun logro hacer que quede como el anterior, estaría muy agradecido.
Como nota: use plot por que con ggplot2 no se podía sobreponer las dos graficas dada la gran diferencia de los ejes y ya que son dos.

Comment: Bienvenido MEMela a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.